# Select camera while in camera view in 2.8

Tags: camera, select

In 2.79 and earlier, I would regularly select the camera while in camera view by right clicking the border edge, in order to move around.

In 2.8 I can't seem to find a way to do it other than selecting the camera from the  outliner, which isn't a huge deal, but is a bit annoying for something that's a big part of my workflow. Is there any way to change this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine in 2.81a  for Linux.  Just make sure you are in object mode, otherwise selection won't work.  Also selection is Left-Click by default, unless you've chosen a different setting in user prefs.

Comment: @Moog works on Windows as well. Alternatively you can also select the camera in the outliner and it will get selected in the viewport as well.

Comment: My apologies, you're right, this does seem to work in new 2.8 blender files. 
However doesn't seem to work when opening files created in older versions... strange. But good to know that it won't be an ongoing issue moving forward.

Comment: In case you encounter UI issues in older projects files, disable *Load UI* when opening the file through *File > Open*.